# can I use Jenkins variables inside a yaml config file?

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Is there any way to capture the users email address who ran the build and put it into the jenkins yml config file?  in other words, can I use a standard JENKINS ENV VAR in my yaml config file that is read into my pipeline?
I am using this plugin: https://engineering.salesforce.com/open-sourcing-the-jenkins-config-driven-pipelines-plugin-9c0becaa5f79

Answer (score 0):

As they use

```
script_to_run: |-
  pip install pipenv
  export PATH=$(python -m site --user-base)/bin:$PATH
```

looks like it's running in `bash`. You may then try e.g. `$JENKINS_HOME` or `$BRANCH_NAME` and see if it works.